# Python regex to go match any string that starts with a string

Tags: python, regex

I don't know much about regexes and am trying to learn them. I am using Python and need to use `re.compile` to make a regex that matches any string that starts with a variable string. The string is variable `url`. Currently I have `re.compile('%s*'%url)`, but it does not seem to work. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you please post your current code, to see if the mistake can be found?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `re.escape(url)`:

```
In [15]: import re

In [16]: url = 'http://stackoverflow.com'

In [17]: pat = re.compile(re.escape(url))

In [18]: pat.match('http://stackoverflow.com')
Out[18]: <_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x8fd4c28>

In [19]: pat.match('http://foo.com') is None
Out [19]: True
```

Answer (score 0):

Though regex would work for this situation, why not use [str.**startswith()**](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.startswith)?  Makes things simpler upon your part and is already built in with python for situations like this.  It also condenses everything that has to be done with your code such as compiling, matching, etc.  So, instead of regex, this is what your code can look like:

```
url = "http://example.com/"
string = "http://example.com is a great site! Everyone check it out!"
if string.startswith(url):
    print 'The string starts with url!'
else:
    print "The string doesn't start with url. Very unfortunate."
```

Comment: That would be fantastic, but I'm actually using it to get fields from the database that match that regex

Comment: What difference does it make if it is regex or a built-in type?

Comment: I agree, if you're only trying to match the start of a string to a url, regex is overkill.

Comment: but I have to say url = x so I can't say url = url.startswith(url)